# Why value coming in string is in bracket

Tags: iphone, nsstring

The value coming in the NSString is in brackets due to which string comparision getting failed and lead to crash. Below is the value coming in NSString.

```
strId:(
17
), strCID:5
```

I am trying to compare the above two strings following with error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-     [__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa357130'
```

Please guide for above what is wrong.

Comment: Because it's an array with a single element in it.

Comment: got your point, but better if you post answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is not a string, it's an array that contains a single element which is a string.

You can also see that the receiver of that message is of the class `__NSArrayI` which is a class for immutable arrays in the NSArray class cluster.